# RouteMap code throwing error

Tags: javascript

I've created this jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ismusidhu/ZHJQX/5/

It is throwing error `Uncaught TypeError: add: rule.route and rule.method must both be non-empty strings`

I've taken the code from Client Sample given on https://github.com/OpenGamma/RouteMap#readme

I know I'm doing something stupid.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple mistake you've made. You're doing:

```
routes.add(rule);
```

But you should be doing:

```
routes.add(rules[rule]);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Even then it is not working. BTW `routes.add(rule);` is as per the first example shown on the link in the question

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will update the documentation. Once I made that change in your code, the next error that was thrown was because your function called "n" does not exist. I figured you had not yet added it.

Comment: I'm sure that I had tried `routes.add(rules[rule]);` and it didn't worked yesterday. It's working now. Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you made any other changes in the fiddle apart from this that it started working?

Comment: I moved your window.n, window.lood_foo_main, window.load_foo definitions up so that they would be defined before your calls to RouteMap just now and that seemed to fix it.